# Django - permissions api - should I encrypt permissions tokens in database for security?

Tags: django, security, encryption

I'm building an application which makes use of a public api. The api allows us to perform actions on behalf of the users of a different app, using permissions; we collect permissions from the user in the form of a `token` and a `secret` which we use to authenticate and perform actions on their behalf.

We store the `token` and `secret` in our database. They are specifically generated for our api application, so whenever we need to use the api to perform an action for a user, we also need to provide our own api credentials; so something along the lines of:

```
from myapp.settings import API_APPID, API_PASS
user.perform_action(api_appid=API_APPID, api_pass=API_PASS, permissions_token=user.permissions_token, permissions_secret=user.permissions_secret)
```

(In reality we generate an authentication header using the permissions token/secret).

I'm wondering if we should be encrypting the permissions token/secret in our database?  My initial thought is no, since the permissions token and password is useless without our own api credentials (stored in our settings.py)

If we were to encrypt the tokens, we'd be storing our private key in settings.py anyway, meaning the security of the application would be just as dependent on the secrecy of our settings file.

Any thoughts? Is there a good reason to encrypt these tokens, or am I right in thinking it would be redundant?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. If anyone compromises your application server, they have the keys they need to get the tokens and the ability to ( as the server) query the database no matter what.

If you didn't need a separate API key, it would protect against simple SQL injection. However, the API, as you say, means that an attacker who learns the token learns nothing useful. This is, of course, assuming the tokens don't contain something sensitive like a users password.

Comment: This is not true. If someone compromises your application server, then you should still try to protect the 3rd party's information. Which you can do with by using something like KMS to add a layer between the DB and the encryption key